# Wif tracing not working with Visual Studio 2013 project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wif, trace

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and tried to do this walk through [How To: Enable WIF Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161102(v=vs.110).aspx). But I **did not find** Identity and Access under Solution Explorer. So how do I enable WIF tracing in Visual Studio 2013.

I even added the xml in the System.Diagnostics section and created the folder C:\logs\, but did not find anything in that folder after logged in. Can someone please enlighten me as to what am I missing?

Comment: Did you actually install WIF first?

Comment: Hi Erik, Are you talking about the Identity and Access tool mentioned(https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e)? This one does not seem to apply to VS 2013. Basically my question is how do I enable WIF tracing with VS 2013? If you are asking about WIF installation, I guess its already integrated with .NET 4.5, so I suppose nothing additional installation is needed.

Comment: If you read the comment by Vittorio Bertoci here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e you will find that WIF works differently in VS2013, and can only be configured (by VS) at template creation time.  You need to create an "organizational accounts" application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft example should work.  System.IdentityModel is the one for .NET 4.5.  Does your app (app pool identity) have access to the c:\logs folder ?  The Tracing thing is not WIF related (it works for WCF and othe rbuilt-in .NET stuff as well) so if you copy/pasted the example your should be ready to go...